# PL/SQL dbms_output adding extra Carriage Return in CLOB

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

When using dbms_output to put a clob with a carriage return it is inserting an additional one, which creates additional line breaks that can be seen when running it in SQL*Plus and using spool to capture it. The database being used is Oracle 11g. For example, running this:

```
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET ECHO OFF SET
VERIFY OFF SET
TRIMOUT ON SET
TRIMSPOOL ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

SPOOL ./TestResult.txt

-- Spooling direct select for comparing results
SELECT 'line 1'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||'line 2' FROM DUAL;

declare
  l_clob clob;
begin
  l_clob := 'line 1'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'line 2';
  dbms_output.put_line(l_clob);
end;
/

SPOOL OFF
```

Produces:

```
line 1
line 2

line 1

line 2
```

With the underlying line breaks going like:

```
[CR][LF]
line 1[CR][LF]
line 2[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
line 1[CR]
[CR][LF]
line 2[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
```

As additional note, the code above is a simplified example to illustrate my issue. In reality, the CRLF line jumps came from a clob column that I cannot modify, but I need to process before creating some client side log files with spool, as I cannot use utl_file or similar functions for creating them. Also this should be handled inside PL/SQL or SQL*Plus if possible, so I am not looking for solutions in the line of eliminating the extra CRs externally with a text editor, sh/bat scripts or similar methods.

I have tried to find why it is inserted or how to get rid of it to no avail, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Include `SET LINESIZE` into your *set* of `SET` commands, e.g.

```
set serveroutput on
set linesize 2000        --> this
spool ..
```

Comment: Same result with set linesize.

Comment: On a similar way, I have also tried to check and increase the serveroutput limit and the dbms_output buffer limit, but the issue persists.

Comment: Try some more SETs: `set sqlbl off`, `set pages 0`.

Comment: I tried the ones you suggested and other usual SQL*Plus clob and format sets like COLSEP, LONGC, WRA or different options for SERVEROUTPUT.
The issue does not seem to came from the SQP*Plus and spool sets, as the line breaks are correctly displayed when directly outputted from a select clause, but it rather seems to be related to the way dbms_output handles the CR charater in either its put methods or the get that is implicitly called when returning.

Answer (score -1):

Use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT.
This procedure places a partial line in the buffer.

On "Database PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference", chapter 100 DBMS_OUTPUT
[PUT Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_output.htm#ARPLS67324)

Comment: Aa explained in the link you provided, put_line is just the same as put but with a line termintaion at the end. In my case the issue is not with the buffer termination, but with CRs inside the content, and using put bears the same result as put_line.

Comment: What operating system are you running SQL*Plus?